# FromBody attribute model is not capturing my data correctly

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I'm using Angular frontend and .NET backend.

I'm sending a FormGroup from the frontend to my backend, but when I hit a breakpoint in my Controller, it says that the FromBody model is capturing the amount as 0.

When I look at DevTools, the API call's Payload is this:
[Request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DefBn.png)

Here is my backend code:

```
    public class DonationAmount
    {
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("create-checkout-session")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CheckoutApiController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([FromBody] DonationAmount donationAmount)
        {
            try
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (StripeException ex)
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea what is going on?

I've tried Googling, Youtube, ChatGPT, matching the casing of the JSON data and the model properties

Comment: Please use Fiddler to capture your HTTP request

Comment: You should be POST-ing `{amount: 5}` json to your endpoint, not `{donationAmount: {amount: 5}}`